# Ordinary Differential Equation Using Separable Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck trying to solve$$2y\,\mathrm dx-x\,\mathrm dy=0.$$What I have done: using the separable equation I got$$2y\,\mathrm dx=x\,\mathrm dy\\\frac1y\,\mathrm dy=\frac2x\,\mathrm dx\\\int\frac1y\,\mathrm dy=\int\frac2x\,\mathrm dx\\\ln(y)=\ln(x)^2+c\\e^{\ln (y)}=e^{2\ln(x)}+e^c\\y=x^2+e^c$$My professor said my answer is not quite right, he said the right answer is $y=c x^2$.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $e^{x^2+c} \neq e^{x^2}+e^c$.

Comment: @IanThank i see it now is it $$e^{x^2+c}=xe^c$$?

Comment: $2\ln(x) = \ln(x^2)$ and not $\ln(x)^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2y\,\mathrm dx=x\,\mathrm dy\\\frac1y\,\mathrm dy=\frac2x\,\mathrm dx\\\int\frac1y\,\mathrm dy=\int\frac2x\,\mathrm dx\\\ln(y)=\ln(x)^2+c$$
The line after this is not correct. It shoul be
$$e^{ln y }=e^{\ln (x^2)+c}$$
$$y=x^2e^c$$
$$y=cx^2$$

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write $\ln c$ instead of simply $c$

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln y &=& 2\ln x + \ln c\\
&=& \ln (cx^2)\\,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Hence, $y=cx^2$.